# How to allocate physical resources for a big data cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, bigdata

I have three servers and I want to deploy Spark Standalone Cluster or Spark on Yarn Cluster on that servers. 
Now I have some questions about how to allocate physical resources for a big data cluster. For example, i want to know whether i can deploy Spark Master Process and Spark Worker Process on the same node. Why?

Server Details:

```
CPU Cores: 24
Memory: 128GB
```

I need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, just put host with Master in slaves. On my test server I have such configuration, master machine is also worker node and there is one worker-only node. Everything is ok

However be aware, that is worker will fail and cause major problem (i.e. system restart), then you will have problem, because also master will be afected.

Edit:
Some more info after question edit :) If you are using YARN (as suggested), you can use Dynamic Resource Allocation. [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/ozax86/spark-on-yarn-with-dynamic-resource-allocation) are some slides about it and [here](https://www.mapr.com/blog/resource-allocation-configuration-spark-yarn) article from MapR. It a very long topic how to configure memory properly for given case, I think that these resources will give you much knowledge about it

BTW. If you have already intalled Hadoop Cluster, maybe try YARN mode ;) But it's out of topic of question

Comment: Thank you for reply. I edited my question. According to you mean. If Spark Master Process was afected, I will not do it.

Comment: @TimothyKoo About allocation, it's a complicated case. Recently I saw very good presentation about it, will link to it and call you when I will find it. Master node will be afected only in very very bad situation, it depends how much resilience do you need - sometimes whole cluster can be down at it is tolerated, sometimes (for example real time jobs) resilience is major topic